# jsPlumb exporte PNG

Tags: jquery, export, png, jsplumb

I'm having problem when exporting to PNG my flowchart, follows the code that makes the export.

```
var el = $('#grafico').get(0);
html2canvas(el, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        $flows = $('> svg', el);
        $flows.each( function() {
            $svg = $(this)
            offset = $svg.position();
            svgStr = this.outerHTML;
            ctx.drawSvg(svgStr, offset.left, offset.top);
        });
        $endpoints = $('._jsPlumb_endpoint > svg', el);
        $endpoints.each(function() {
            $svg = $(this)
            offset = $svg.parent().position();
            svgStr = this.outerHTML;
            ctx.drawSvg(svgStr, offset.left, offset.top);
        });
        //# Convert canvas to Blob
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            //# Download Blob canvas
            saveAs(blob, 'teste.png')
        });
    }
});
```

The elements, it exports the correct position, but the connectors are completely out of alignment.[image]

Below is how it should be.

### [image]

---

Comment: Wild guess: `offset = $svg.position();` for $flows while it is `offset = $svg.parent().position();` for $endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The flow chart container has been set attributes. such as top, margin-left or others. In my case, the chart container top value is 59, and margin-left value is 240. So if I change code for $flow.

```
ctx.drawSvg(svgStr, offset.left - 240, offset.top - 59);
```

And it works well, I think you can check your div layout, and will find that you need to pay attention to whether position is absolute or relative, and left, top , margin attributes for '*grafico*' container.